# How to change priority of program in system monitor?

Tags: process-priority

I'm trying to change priority of processes so the games I play have a higher priority for performance reasons, but I cant figure it out how to that. I've done some searching and found that you have to change the programs "nice" value (or something like that), however I always get lost and confused when following their explanations.

Answer (score 2):

To change priority of a process, open system-monitor with root privileges. But if you are using Ubuntu 18.04+, GNOME system monitor which is installed by default is a snap package which fails to open with root privileges. So, install gnome-system-monitor` from APT first. Run:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-system-monitor
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

Run GNOME System Monitor with root privileges:

```
sudo -H gnome-system-monitor
```

*Right click* on the process for which you want to change priority.

[image: Screenshot GNOME system monitor]